# Automatic Cookie Handling C#/.NET HttpWebRequest+HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, .net, cookies

Is there any way to automatically handle cookies in .NET with the HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse objects? I'm preferably looking for an equivalent to LWP::UserAgent and its behaviour (perl), only in a .NET environment.

Any suggestions or advice?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the [CookieContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookiecontainer.aspx) class. If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you have separate objects for request & response, and you want to transfer the *response* cookie collection into the next *request* cookie collection automatically. Try using this code:

```
CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
int cookieCount = cookieJar.Count;
```

Once you create a `cookieJar` and set it to the request's CookieContainer, it will store any cookies that come from the response, so in the example above, the cookie jar's count will be `1` once it visits Google.com. The cookie container properties of the request & response above will store a pointer to the cookieJar, so the cookies are automatically handled and shared between the objects.