# cookies stored on login for next page

Tags: c#, cookies

How can i make it so my c# application gets cookie data when it uses http so it can be stored for the next page.

For example, it logs in.. Then it enters another webpage which requires the same data 
received from when logging in.

Here is the code:

[Code!](http://pastebin.com/cGXcRRMK)

Comment: What's wrong with HttpWebResponse.Cookies?

Comment: It doesnt continue with the same session , i need it to store the session throughout opening the websites

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "c#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET application? Windows Forms?

Comment: Nah this is a c# application, just console mode. It connects with http but then connects to other websites.

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few examples of creating and retrieving cookies.

[Automatic Cookie Handling C#/.NET HttpWebRequest+HttpWebResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571964/automatic-cookie-handling-c-net-httpwebrequesthttpwebresponse)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd920298(v=vs.95).aspx

It's advisable to avoid storing sensitive data in cookies. If you are, then at least encrypt it using something like AesCryptoServiceProvider: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider.aspx

hopefully this helps.

Comment: Hey there, i tried the cookiejar thing in the first link, i keep retrieving 0 as a value when printing to console. Which means i get 0 cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Add Cookie :

```
HttpCookie aCookie = new HttpCookie("userName");
aCookie.Value = "pranay";
aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);
```

Retrieve Cookie :

```
if(Request.Cookies["userName"] != null)
{
    HttpCookie aCookie = Request.Cookies["userName"];
    Label1.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(aCookie.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using querystring data?

```
yourUrl.aspx?username=mrWonderful&password=myPass
```

and then parse that login data on the next page.

Comment: QueryStrings are great, but passing sensitive data like a username or passwords in a query string well your making it easier for malicious users to get access to your websites user accounts.