# using cookies (httpWebRequest,c#)

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I read whole answers about httpWebRequest and Cookies in the site, But my problem is still unsolved. I have a winform application that logs into a website (logs correctly) but I can't use it's cookies to still logged in for another pages, I tried many solutions such as using PHPSESSID , using a single CookieContainer in both Requests but none of them was effective.
Here's my code :

```
           HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("(Login page)");

        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webRequest.KeepAlive = true;

        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes("username=uname&password=pass&submit=Button");

        webRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
        CookieContainer CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        webRequest.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;


        Stream newStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
        newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        newStream.Close();
        HttpWebResponse webResponse;
        webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        HttpWebRequest webRequest1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("(My control panel page)");
        webRequest1.Method = "GET";
        webRequest1.KeepAlive = true;
        webRequest1.CookieContainer=new CookieContainer();
        foreach (Cookie cook in webResponse.Cookies)
        {
            webRequest1.CookieContainer.Add(cook);
        }
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest1.GetResponse();



        string html;
        using (Stream strmresponse = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(strmresponse, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                html = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        textBox1.Text = html;
```

Comment: ContentType isn't set for the 2nd request. Maybe this somehow affects server? Do you see a typo in  webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";? And BTW I don't think this content-type is applicable for GET request.

Comment: Usually you would just use the same cookie container, not copy from one to another: webRequest1.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;  If that doesn't work, capture the network traffic and compare with a browser.

Comment: @bmm6o how can I capture the network traffic?

Comment: @RamanZhylich I don't know what's the ContetType property, what's the suitable value for ContentType of 2nd request ?

Comment: With something like wireshark

Comment: @RamanZhylich I changed it but it don't work.

Comment: @bmm6o I don't know net programming as well as you know and my project doesn't focus on this subject , I just need it to read some news from my account. is there anyway to make this code work correctly ?

Comment: It's possible in theory, but there's only enough information here for people to guess, not offer definitive solutions.  If you post the wire capture of a working session (browser) and a non-working one (your code) we might be able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you still care, but check the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571964/automatic-cookie-handling-c-net-httpwebrequesthttpwebresponse) out, as it shows how to re-use cookies for multiple requests.