# .net HTTP POST Method cookies disabled

Tags: .net, http, post, cookies

I'm try to login to a site (can't give the URL, it's only intranet) using POST and C# (or VB).
I get the following error :

> This system requires the use of HTTP cookies to verify authorization
>   information. Our system has detected that your browser has disabled
>   HTTP cookies, or does not support them. Please refer to the Help page
>   in your browser for more information on how to correctly configure
>   your browser for use with this system.

I use the following code:

```
var cookies = new CookieContainer();
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://.......");
request.CookieContainer = cookies;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
{
    writer.Write("user=XX&pass=XX");
}

using (var responseStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
{
    var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatic Cookie Handling C#/.NET HttpWebRequest+HttpWebResponse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571964/automatic-cookie-handling-c-net-httpwebrequesthttpwebresponse)

Comment: you need to transfer the cookies from the login request to all subsequent HTTP requests as shown in the question that I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I solve this?

By looking at legitimate traffic and replaying that from code. My guess: the login page sets a cookie and/or a hidden form value, either or both of which you have to POST to the login page.

So: start [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), request the login page with a browser, login, confirm above theory and rebuild from code:

1. GET login form with CookieContainer attached
2. Read login form and store hidden value(s) (if required)
3. Do a POST with CookieContainer from 1 and form fields from 2
4. ???
5. Profit